# Change the background color of a DataGridCell based on the context value. (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like to change the background color of a `DataGridCell` based on the context value.  Currently the the content is text.  As shown I'm binding to a data source that generates the columns.  I'm not sure how to tell a `DataTrigger` to bind to its own value without specifying a tag for each column.  I have many columns and would prefer not to have 50 `DataTrigger` tags.

Here is my xaml:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="10"/>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Ultimately I would like to provide a range of values that would meet the trigger.  Such as any value 10 to 20 ( 10 <= value <= 20).

Answer (score 2):

You should use a TemplateColumn as shown below, and in the Loaded event handler, check the condition and take action.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Area, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

 private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tb = ((TextBox)sender);
            if (tb.Text == 10)
            {
                tb.Background = Brushes.Plum;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following code snippet which shows a data trigger that changes the `Background` property of a `label` to green when the bound property `YourProperty`
equals “10”:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=YourProperty}" Value="10">
               <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="Green" />
           </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I'm looking for.  I would prefer not binding to a specific proper of my bound object as that would require ~50 binds as I have ~50 columns.  Also this will color an entire row in the DataGrid.  I would prefer that only a single TextBox/DataGridCell is changed based on its own value.